# CSS Icon vertical aligning

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve the following alignments in css with minimal css elements:

Middle:

```
==============================================================
= [icon]                                                     =
= [    ] Text                                                =
= [    ]                                                     =
==============================================================
```

Bottom:

```
==============================================================
= [icon]                                                     =
= [    ]                                                     =
= [    ] Text                                                =
==============================================================
```

Right Middle:

```
==============================================================
=                                                     [    ] =
=  Text                                               [    ] =
=                                                     [    ] =
==============================================================
```

Right Bottom:

```
==============================================================
=                                                     [    ] =
=                                                     [    ] =
=  Text                                               [    ] =
==============================================================
```

Middle is REALLY easy:

Assume text line-height = 10px, icon height = 30px

```
<div class="container">
    Text
</div>

<div class="container right">
    Text
</div>

.container {
    line-height: 30px;
    background: url(...) no-repeat center left
    padding-left: 38px;
}
.container.right {
    line-height: 30px;
    background: url(...) no-repeat center right
    padding-right: 38px;
}
```

The question is: How do I do the bottom alignment?

Comment: `background: url(...) no-repeat bottom right` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way you can align elements vertically from the parent element is by setting it to display as a table-cell with `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:`. If that isn't acceptable, you must do it from child elements and relative positioning.

http://jsfiddle.net/VdvmJ

Comment: Epic dude, I love you! To make it clear. Set the `height` to the size of the image, set `display: table-cell;` and set the `vertical-align` on that same element to be whatever orientation you want.

Comment: Yes. And if you keep each thing you want to do separate in the CSS, you can use it as a sort of switch so you don't have to code each possible combination of layouts.

Comment: I just needed a tool to put the icon middle/top/bottom aligned, the rest is just what icon to use. :P

Answer (score 1):

Its not a big deal I think. First set the background image position to top left and then increase the line height according to your image height.

[**Check this jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/ySYTb/)

For right aligning the section, I set `text-align:right;` also.

Hope you are trying to do this.

Comment: I can't use that solution, the reason being that I don't know what the height of the text is. I assumed it was 10px in the example but this style needs to be applied to many elements each of which have different font sizes. Also, it's a bit wrong, http://jsfiddle.net/ySYTb/2/ see the borders. It pushes the actual parent to be bigger than intended.